# 'Level' still seems periodic after Season Decomposition

Tags: time-series, trend, exponential-smoothing

I've used tbats for this transformation:

```
Exponential smoothing state space model with Box-Cox transformation, ARMA errors, Trend and Seasonal components
```

My (hourly) data has daily and weekly seasons, and `tbats` seems to be the best way to make sense of this kind of data.

Here are the results -

[image: 1]

The `level` graph looks like it still has plenty of daily seasonality remaining. I'm trying to understand how can such daily seasonality remain after removal of a perfect daily season (`season1`)?

Secondly, what method would you suggest to make the level smoother? A simple/exponential MA doesn't cut it. I'm basically interested in finding out changepoints in the data, as accurately as possible. Is there a clever way to manipulate `level` to bring out this property?

Comment: A couple of points to consider: (1) the range of "level" is about $0.05$ (and the daily fluctuation even smaller) compared with $0.25$ for "season1" and (2) you you might take averages of level for individual hours (ignoring days) to see if there is a much of a pattern.  My guess is that the real daily seasonal pattern changed very slightly from beginning to end (especially in the final $8$ days) and this is causing some of the apparent pattern in "level"

Comment: You're right, then daily seasonal pattern had an increase within their last 8 days. Is there a way to account for this kind of increase? Does TBATS limit me here?

Comment: Hmm I removed the final 8 days from my dataset, and I'm still getting a graph with peaks for every day. Is there a way to smoothen such a graph *without* losing sight of change points?